# Efficient Test For Commuting Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, matrix-decomposition

I know that if $A$ and $B$ are two Hermitian matrices, then $A B= B A$ if and only if their eigenspaces coincide [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices#Characterization_in_terms_of_eigenvectors). 
In order to apply this test one need to compute eigenvectors of both $A$ and $B$ and then determine if they are linearly independent, which is computationally expensive.

The other potentially applicable test for commuting is [*simultaneous triangularisability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Simultaneous_triangularisability). Two matrices are *simultaneously triangularisable* if there exist basis in which they both take upper triangular form. I do not know how to use this property in order to numerically establish commuting property  of two matrices.  However, I believe that direct implementation of such a test will be very computationally expensive.

Are there any other criteria I could encode in MATLAB in order  to determine whether two (Hermitian,  real symmetric) matrices commute?

Comment: Simply multiplying both $AB,BA$ and testing for (numerical) equality would be an $O(n^3)$ computation.

Comment: @hardmath  I did not think of that. I apologize for the dumb question. Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Note that since $A,B$ are Hermitian, one needs only compute (in exact precision) $AB$ and test it for being Hermitian.  Still $O(n^3)$ (unless fast multiplication is used), but saves a constant factor.

Comment: ... and $n^3$ can be approved: Using [Strassen multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm#Asymptotic_complexity), we have $O(n^{2.8\cdots})$